# No longer able to create Gifs with last update

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I cut videos to under 6 seconds but the gif button doesn't appear. This function has been disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Same case. I guess it's gone. Noted that sendings gifs "normally" still doesn't work as well. However, old <6sec gifs sent before can be forwarded successfully.